# Building Sql query string processing

Tags: sql, select, subquery, sql-like

I need help in building up one SQL query

My requirement is to get folders present in the path passed (Excluding subfolders)

When I pass the parameter like
input : `D245E7DA\Entertainment\`

expected output:

```
D245E7DA\Entertainment\Movies\
D245E7DA\Entertainment\Series\
```

not expected this output:

```
D245E7DA\Entertainment\Movies\
D245E7DA\Entertainment\Series\
D245E7DA\Entertainment\Series\Ramayan
D245E7DA\Entertainment\Series\Geetha
```

Comment: You can also use stripping functions. Just remove all data after second "\" That should work.

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `like`:

```
where folder like concat(<input>, '/%') and
      folder not like concat(<input>, '/%/%')
```